# Change the Type of date in Php Myadmin

Tags: php, mysql, date

Is there any way to change the type of date column,it shows like "0000-00-00" means in YYYY-MM-DD But i want to store date in DD-MM-YYY Format. i know that it can be done by Formatting(Use the explode function),but i don't want to explode the date.is there any way to do this without formatting???

Comment: The right answer is to store it as-is and format it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The date is not "stored as YYYY-MM-DD", that's just how it is shown to you. It is actually stored in some internal format for representing time. You can format it differently when you select it from the database (e.g. `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(columnName, '%d-%m-%Y')`) or in PHP using the date formatting functions (e.g. `echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime($result['columnName']))`). Under no circumstances should you simply `explode` the string.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html

Better stick with it. At application side while displaying it you can anytime change format as per your requirement.

@deceze Thanks !!

Comment: "MySQL **retrieves and displays** DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format." - It doesn't *store* it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to just set format to MM-DD-YYYY

Comment: actually i also want that at the time of insertion the date the format is also should same.